# SetText For EditText

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-edittext

I am creating an update profile page and after getting data from the database, i want to set the values in edittexts so i can edit them. when i tried it it gave me errors. Please advice me on what to do. Thanks!

This is my ProfileActivity.java Class

```
package com.example.fproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProfileActivity extends Activity {

EditText firstnameBox, lastnameBox, departmentBox, officeBox, emailBox, phonenoBox, passwordBox, statusBox, confirm_passwordBox;
private Button register;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String user;
SessionManagement session;
GetIPAddress getIPaddress = new GetIPAddress();
private static String url_get_user_data;    // products JSONArray
JSONArray data = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    session = new SessionManagement(getApplicationContext()); 
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("login_pref", 0);
    user = sp.getString(session.KEY_EMAIL, null);

    url_get_user_data = getIPaddress.getIP()+"get_user_data_for_profile.php";

    firstnameBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.update_firstname);
    lastnameBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.update_lastname);
    departmentBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.update_department);
    officeBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.update_office);
    emailBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.update_email);
    phonenoBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.update_phoneno);
    passwordBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.update_password);
    confirm_passwordBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.update_confirm_password);
    new GetUserData().execute();
    register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.update_register); 
    register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

   }

class GetUserData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user));
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_user_data, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("User Data: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAGh
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received product details
                    JSONArray userObj = json
                            .getJSONArray("data"); // JSON Array

                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject user = userObj.getJSONObject(0);             


                    //firstnameBox.setText(user.getString("firstname"));
                    firstnameBox.setText("lsdf;skdjf", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                    /*lastnameBox.setText(user.getString("lastname"));
                    departmentBox.setText(user.getString("department"));
                    officeBox.setText(user.getString("office"));
                    emailBox.setText(user.getString("email"));
                    phonenoBox.setText(user.getString("phoneno"));
                    passwordBox.setText(user.getString("password"));
                    statusBox.setText(user.getString("status"));
*/

            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AdminHomeActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.profile, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

This is the Logcat Error

```
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:266)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:3392)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:597)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:645)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:3691)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:7141)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:3866)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:6932)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:7058)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:918)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:615)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:518)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:74)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:85)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:288)  
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2814)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at com.example.fproject.ProfileActivity$GetUserData.doInBackground(ProfileActivity.java:100)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at com.example.fproject.ProfileActivity$GetUserData.doInBackground(ProfileActivity.java:1)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
 04-06 22:31:25.725: E/AndroidRuntime(644):     ... 4 more
```

Thanks!..Please advice me on what to do

Comment: You are trying to change UI from a background thread.

Comment: yes i'm trying to change UI from a background thread.

Comment: You should not do that :)

Comment: Any updates to the UI should be done from the UI thread (main thread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to change your UI from the AsyncTask's doInBackground(), but runs on a background thread, not the main thread (or UI thread). That's what onPostExecute() is for, since AsyncTask makes it run on the UI thread right after doInBackground finishes.

My suggestion:

1. Change the result type of your AsyncTask class to JSONObject:

   `class GetUserData extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>` {
2. Change the return type of doInBackground() to JSONObject:

   `protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {`
3. Return the JSONObject object `user`, and remove all the UI-related code you commented out and also line 100

   `JSONObject user = userObj.getJSONObject(0);
   return user;`
4. Put the UI-related code in a new method onPostExecute()

`@Override
protected void onPostExecute (JSONObject user) {
    if (user == null) {
        return; // nothing to be done
    }

```
try {
    firstnameBox.setText(user.getString("firstname"));
    lastnameBox.setText(user.getString("lastname"));
    departmentBox.setText(user.getString("department"));
    officeBox.setText(user.getString("office"));
    emailBox.setText(user.getString("email"));
    phonenoBox.setText(user.getString("phoneno"));
    passwordBox.setText(user.getString("password"));
    statusBox.setText(user.getString("status"));
} catch(JSONException e) {
  // process your exception
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change UI from a background thread which is not allowed. You should Override the onPostExecute for AsyncTask and use that to update your UI. Your AsyncTask should look like:

```
    class GetUserData extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

         @Override
         protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
              //Code to get user
              return user;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject user) {
             try {
                firstnameBox.setText(user.getString("firstname"));
             } catch (Exception e) {}

         }
     }
```

Comment: ive done this and it still gives me a JavaNullPointerException error

Comment: i cannot post images but this is it....04-07 00:43:49.825: E/AndroidRuntime(809): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 00:43:49.825: E/AndroidRuntime(809): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 00:43:49.825: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at com.example.fproject.ProfileActivity$GetUserData.onPostExecute(ProfileActivity.java:122)
04-07 00:43:49.825: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at com.example.fproject.ProfileActivity$GetUserData.onPostExecute(ProfileActivity.java:1)
04-07 00:43:49.825: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:590)
04-07 00:43:49.825: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at

Comment: Make sure the user is not null. Can you also post an updated version of your code you code.

Comment: which line is line 122

Comment: pDialog.dismiss(); is on line 122

Comment: remove that line, or check if pDialog is null before dismissing it